# Speed to collect wort from the mash tun for maximum efficiency

Tags: beer, mash, wort

I want to optimize my efficiency, and I was wondering is the speed at which I collect my wort has an incidence on it.

Right now I would say that I collect 1 liter of wort each 30-45 seconds. I get between 65% and 70% efficiency. I am using a 10 gallons mash tun.

- Is that too fast?
- Will lowering the flow increase my efficiency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are batch sparging the rate has minimal impact of efficiency.
If you are fly sparging in most certainly can have an effect, slower is usually better.  Finding the balance between a speedy enough brew session and decent efficiency is a personal choice.

Shooting for 75% is probably fine and some report getting better beer without pushing into the 80+% range.  Slowing down your sparge just a little bit more would probably get you there.

Last point. If you beer tastes great there might really be no need to change your efficiency.